# Avast malware-gen popups on mac when going onto google chrome website

Tags: virus, chrome

Just today, I went onto google chrome and began using normal websites such as Google drive. However, the moment I went to these sites, my Mac began showing Avast popups to the side that said :
[image]

They keep popping up, and only stop once I quit google chrome. Is there any solution to this? Is this a false positive that avast often reports?

Comment: Have you asked Avast?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like [you are not the only one](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=197572.0). Other people have reported similar or identical problems.
It appears that an update issued today has fixed this problem.

Please try to update your install of Avast and see if it fixes the issue.

**EDIT** : DO NOT RUN A FULL SYSTEM SCAN! PEOPLE HAVE REPORTED IT HAS CORRUPTED THEIR SYSTEMS!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I have not seen this before but since you refer to Google Drive it might be possible that you have an infected file in your cloud storage. *Although it would be a bit strange if Avast scans the actual file contents on your cloud storage (when only shown the relation to the file in a browser) as well as alarming the users based on a filename only.*

Secondly, it might be possible that you have some kind of malicious browser plug-in or other kind of malware infection? Did you do some full system scans with the proper antivirus and anti malware software?

Thirdly, are you using some kind of proxy,  VPN, uncommon DNS server or openly shared network? Those might be able to spoof or inject something using some kind of Man-in-the-Middle (MiTM) attack for example.